# Visual Studio: Creating a multi-value parameter using multiple stored procs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, visual-studio-2015

I am working in Visual Studio to build a report with multiple stored procs.  My problem is the user needs to be able to pick from a multi-value parameter, what stored proc they need to run.  The stored procs are for different departments needing the same type of data.

ie.
-sp_MissingImagesFinance

-sp_MissingImagesHR

-sp_MissingImagesAdmin

I need to create one drop-down parameter for the user to be able to pick one of the above sp's based on their department and then they would run the report using their particular sp.  Is there a way to do this?  I do not have permissions to modify any sp's so I have to work with what I have.

Comment: an employee should only have access to one of these or any combination of these?

Comment: An employee would only have access to one of these at any time.

Comment: Then i'd use a look up table which stores which one they have access to based on their dept. i.e. EmpID and SP Name or a INT column then check the logic and automatically call the correct procedure based off who the user is. No sense in letting them choose which one to run since they should only be able to run one, right?

Comment: Well, let me rephrase.  They will have permission to access all of them, but they will only be viewing one at a time.  There is no instance where'd they'd pick both the Admin and Finance to display on the same instance.

Comment: This is pretty sparse on details. But I think I would create a new procedure that receives the name of the procedure you want to run. Then decide which one to run based on the parameter. I realize you might not be able to change the existing procedures but you should discourage the use of sp_ (or any prefix really). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Samantha. I think @SeanLange solution would be an easy solution. And +1 his comment on NOT naming procedures sp_ which doesn't mean "Stored Procedure" though many people use it or usp for User Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a driver stored procedure similar to this. You would only need to pass in the selected option this way. The other option is something like Jonathan Wilcock posted in his answer.

```
create procedure MissingImagesReport
    (@ReportName varchar(50)) 
as
    set nocount on;

    if @ReportName = 'Finance'
        exec sp_MissingImagesFinance

    if @ReportName = 'HR'
        exec sp_MissingImagesHR

    if @ReportName = 'Admin'
        exec sp_MissingImagesAdmin
```

As I mentioned in my comments I would urge your team to stop using `sp_` or even better, to stop using prefixes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a ComboBox, then all you need is something along the lines of:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ComboBox1.Text, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // or whatever you need
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new to sql so I'm not following your example you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I was less than clear.  You said you were working in Visual Studio, so I rather assumed that you were writing a small c# windows app with a form to allow users to run the report.  The above code snippet was an illustration of how to call the SQL server from c#.  It would help, if you could be a little more specific as to what you are doing (and how).